# Error: no writecb in Transform class.?

Tags: npm, gulp

Good day. Help me please.

There are some versions.

**npm v3.10.6**

**node v4.5.**

**"gulp-file-include": "^0.14.0",**

**"gulp-remove-html": "^1.1.2"**

There is part of gulpfile.js

```
fileinclude    = require('gulp-file-include'),
gulpRemoveHtml = require('gulp-remove-html')

gulp.task('buildhtml', function() {
  gulp.src(['app/*.html'])
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@'
    }))
    .pipe(gulpRemoveHtml())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

There is result after running "gulp buildhtml". The problem appears today.

```
[11:31:46] Starting 'buildhtml'... [11:31:46] Finished 'buildhtml' after 8.83 ms events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: no writecb in Transform class
    at afterTransform (C:\Projects\Projects\project1\node_modules\gulp-file-include\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:74:40)
    at TransformState.afterTransform (C:\Projects\Projects\project1\node_modules\gulp-file-include\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:58:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.fileInclude [as _transform] (C:\Projects\Projects\project1\node_modules\gulp-file-include\lib\index.js:49:9)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (C:\Projects\Projects\project1\node_modules\gulp-file-include\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:159:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (C:\Projects\Projects\project1\node_modules\gulp-file-include\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:147:83)
    at doWrite (C:\Projects\Projects\project1\node_modules\gulp-file-include\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:313:64)
    at writeOrBuffer (C:\Projects\Projects\project1\node_modules\gulp-file-include\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:302:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (C:\Projects\Projects\project1\node_modules\gulp-file-include\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:241:11)
    at write (C:\Projects\Projects\project1\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:623:24)
    at flow (C:\Projects\Projects\project1\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:632:7)
    at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (C:\Projects\Projects\project1\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:664:5)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at emitReadable_ (C:\Projects\Projects\project1\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:448:10)
    at emitReadable (C:\Projects\Projects\project1\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:444:5)
    at readableAddChunk (C:\Projects\Projects\project1\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:187:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Gulp 4.0 alpha 3, Downgrade to Gulp 4.0 alpha 2 with

**npm install -S gulpjs/gulp#6d71a65**